# jquery and grouping checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So this is what I have:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
   $().ready(function() {
     var allVals = [];
     $("input[name^=utType]").each(function() {
       var input = $(this);   
       var name = input.attr('name');    
       var num = /\d+$/.exec(name)[0]; 
       if ($(this).checked) {
         allVals.push($(this).val());
         alert(allVals);
       }
     });
   });
</script>
```

and I have a form with:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table width="70%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <label>All</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType1" id="utType1" value="all">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <label>E</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType1" id="utType1" value="e">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <label>G</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType1" id="utType1" value="g">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <label>S</label><br /> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType1" id="utType1" value="w">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <label>W</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType1" id="utType1" value="s">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
         <label>All</label><br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="utType2" id="utType2" value="all">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <label>E</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType2" id="utType2" value="e">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <label>G</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType2" id="utType2" value="g">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <label>S</label><br /> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType2" id="utType2" value="w">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <label>W</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="utType1" id="utType1" value="s">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

Several things that I will need to do: if "All" is checked, check all the other checkboxes in the same `<tr>`; if one of them is unchecked then uncheck the "all" checkbox in that row. Also, I have to store the checked values for each row with the id to process the form.
Grr, today is not my day.

Comment: i had to modify the script to:

$().ready(function() {
var allVals = [];
$("input[name^=utType]").each(function() {
 var input = $(this);   
 var name = input.attr('name');    
 var num = /\d+$/.exec(name)[0]; 
 $(this).click(function() {
 if ($("#utType"+num).attr('checked',true)) {
   allVals.push($(this).val());
  alert(allVals);
 }
 });});

});


not there yet.

Comment: One error: the "id" attribute of elements must be unique on the page. And to use it in conjunction with a <label> use <label for="utType1_1">e</label><br /><input type="checkbox" name="utType1" id="utType1_1" value="all" />

Answer (score 1):

Try the code at http://jsbin.com/ipuzo. The names of the inputs are no longer important, as the code works on a relationship basis (parent sibling child etc).

In terms of a PHP scripting at the recieving end, grouped checkboxes should be named `foo[]`, or the likes. Identical ids are not valid either. Since the form needn't submit the all checkbox, it has had its `name` removed and replaced with a class.

A few HTML things have also been fixed: `<input />` is a self-closing tag, and there are better ways than `align="center"` to center tables.